# Connect to VPN only when outside office LAN

Tags: networking, vpn, group-policy

I'm trying to figure out a way to make domain clients connect to office LAN using VPN only when it's physically disconnected to the said LAN.

I've found [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772449.aspx) and [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee431700(v=ws.10).aspx) detailed official guides. As far as I understand, it will only make domain members connect to the specified VPN; even if the domain member is already within the LAN the VPN is meant to connect to, essentially a redundant exercise.

- How do I make it so that it ensures it's outside the LAN before connecting to VPN? How can a PC identify a specific network (i.e. what can it use to identify networks so that I may prepare it)?
- Must the log in script always be obtained from the DC? Can I make it so that a copy permanently copies to all members when I create the GPO?

**PS** Can anyone familiar with using the above GPO provide an example L2TP/IPSec XML?

Comment: A VPN connection is usually initiated and established by a user action. Are you saying that these computers are automatically connecting to the VPN?

Comment: @joeqwerty It is not currently (nothing configured yet), but it sure can. Domain GPO enforcement would basically make it's members do so.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. GPO enforcement would make `what` so? I'm asking you if the VPN connection is initiated by the user. Yes or No?

Comment: @joeqwerty To be accurate, a domain user logging in triggers the VPN connection.

Answer (score 0):

DirectAccess will do exactly what you're asking for and handles the bits you're asking about (network location awareness, GPO.)

Comment: Some guidance and references, please?

Comment: I looked it up myself. Ultimate/Enterprise restriction makes it pretty much unfeasible. Further, the domain is to be created using Samba, there's actually no Windows Server on the network to actually provide that service.

Comment: Requiring Windows Enterprise doesn't make it infeasible for the general case. And yes, it does require Windows servers and a Windows domain, which is generally implied when you're talking about Windows workstations and GPOs. If you have a serious budget restriction and don't have a Windows domain, that would have been worth mentioning. As is, you don't even tell us what VPN technology you're using today.

Comment: True, however, I only had enforcement using GPO in mind, so did not feel it necessary to mention the Samba situation. I'm looking at implementing IPSec/L2TP using SoftEther.